# Waterline - Postgres - DataTypes

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, types, sails.js

I am having difficulties with Waterline models and creating the Postgres tables related to those models.

No matter what I do to create a varchar(n) in the table through a model, it converts the attribute to text. And bigint also is being converted to integer!

Should I change the ORM?

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As a side note: `varchar` and `text` are the same in Postgres, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In theory, Waterline is supposed to work without needing any knowledge about the underlying db. If you want to manage your db to that level, you would probably want to find a way to not use waterline (though I know that's not natural when it comes pre-packaged). Why are the details of the column types so important? Are waterline-supported restrictions not enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a more pleasant approach, using Waterline to "RUD" in "CRUD" but not to "C" - create! This because Waterline can be very "bad" at creating intermediary tables, primary keys (composite keys) and etc. So what I do today is this:

1. Compose a full `.sql` file archive to create indexes and tables.
2. Create the database once. (Alter if needed).
3. Declare all the tables as models. Just insert the type, primary key (if it is a single one) and [lifecycle callbacks](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/lifecycle-callbacks.md).
4. Make sure that `config/models.js` is set to `migrate : safe`.

Conclusion: I can insert, read and delete rows with Waterline, but I don't trust it (performance-wise) to create my tables. [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) on the other hand is a much more mature ORM and can be used if you need it. For me the hybrid `waterline` + `SQL` is sufficient.

EDIT: My models dont have any aggregation (like `my_pets: { model: pet}` ), just row names and types, as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sails supported datatype:

String, text, integer, float, date, datetime, boolean, binary, array, json, mediumtext, longtext, objectid

If you need to specify exact length -> varchar(n), you need to use supported data type as shown above, or sails provide option called query.

`Model.query()` method which you can use to perform any kind of query you want.

```
var queryString='CREATE TABLE if not exists sailsusers.test (id INT NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(45) NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))'
 Test.query(queryString,function(err,a){
    if(err)
      return console.log(err);
    console.log(a,'\n',b);
    res.ok();
 });
```